# Angular looking for missing file when building a library project

Tags: angular

I want to build a library project in my angular workspace, but when I tell angular cli to build it i get this error.

```
× Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode.
EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, link 'H:\Projects\TimeCapture\ClientApp\.angular\cache\15.2.7\ng-packagr\tmp\dc5da8d2' -> 'H:\Projects\TimeCapture\ClientApp\.angular\cache\15.2.7\ng-packagr\content-v2\sha512\f3\5f\64128cf4936ea3cad4bce76732158bee83fb2d9a68276d436238a7b272b69ba6a18f63751202b6a65de7dd113b4b064aa27249ea28e9a10569de88c36f22'
```

The advice I found for EISDIR errors is to make sure the file exists and is a file, but the file name changes every time.

Any way to fix it?